# Highcharts + boost.js: Styling is screwed up using 10 or more series

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am trying to set up a Highcharts chart with multiple data series, each containing up to thousands of points.
Therefore I am using the boost.js module, which already leads to great speed improvements.

Unfortunately the styling is completely screwed up as early as I use 10 or more data series.

**Expected behaviour / styling works fine** (boost.js enabled and less than 10 series):

https://jsfiddle.net/k0o1gcxa/14/

**Actual behaviour / styling does not work** (boost.js enabled and 10 series):

https://jsfiddle.net/qr8v3nqa/4/

```
<script foo></script>
```

Any clue how to fix this? Disabling boost.js makes it work for more than 10 series, but the performance is really really poor...

Thanks and cheers!

UPDATE:
Issue is already reported at github, see comment...

Comment: Isn't that reported on the Highcharts github? See [#6602](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6602) and [#6600](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6600).

Comment: @PawełFus indeed, somehow I missed them. Thanks for pointing to the issues!